# Can 70 mm Kodak Ektachrome film survive in +200 to -200 degrees Celsius (+392 to -328 degrees Fahrenheit) temperatures?

Tags: cold, heat

I've seen radiation issues on filmstock where it kind of lightens up the image, lowers contrast. Deep sea cold, or near volcanic temperatures could affect the filmstock/roll.

Comment: I don't know but i am betting that 392 deg f will melt the film completely if not to the point that it all sticks together. Again i don't know but  i think The cold would not damage it unless you tried to use  it / unroll at that temp then it would break. I freeze film and use it, freezing is freezing unless some crystallization  thing would happen to the emulsion at that temp. try it and let us know.

Answer (score 3):

The 70mm film probably has Estar base - I am sure the temperatures allowed are published somewhere. There is also the emulsion which melts around 50C. Higher temps wil permanently damage the image.

As far as the low temperatures, it will most likely survive -200C, which is approx around liquid nitrogen temp. Anything around -200C will become extremely brittle. So you will have to be careful about manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, leaning towards probably.  A point in your favor is that NASA used Ektachrome film in the space program and some rather famous photographs were made in space where the extremes of temperature and radiation vary widely.

Hasselblad 550C medium format cameras were used more than any other type in the early years of the space program, and they used 70mm film.

Here is an except from [Photography During Apollo](https://history.nasa.gov/apollo_photo.html):

> Each film magazine would typically yield 160 color and 200 black and
>   white pictures on special film. Kodak was asked by NASA to develop
>   thin new films with special emulsions. On Apollo 8, three magazines
>   were loaded with 70 mm wide, perforated Kodak Panatomic-X
>   fine-grained, 80 ASA, b/w film, two with Kodak Ektachrome SO-168, one
>   with Kodak Ektachrome SO-121, and one with super light-sensitive Kodak
>   2485, 16,000 ASA film. There were 1100 color, black and white, and
>   filtered photographs returned from the Apollo 8 mission.

Comment: The cameras used for EVA activity in the 1960s by NASA were modified and used in ways to protect the internals from extreme temperatures, especially heat. They had external heat shielding. Film cameras were only exposed to the extreme temperatures for very limited time periods before being stored back inside environmentally controlled spacecraft. The internal temperature of the film magazines didn't allow the film to heat to anywhere near the same temperatures as moon rocks (max of 123ºC) or external parts of spacecraft.

Comment: @MichaelClark Your absolutely right.  The OP did not specify what type of camera or application, but the only place I knew of that offered such extremes is extra-atmosphere and thus I went that route.  I was actually wondering why the OP asked about the film but not the camera, or other methods.

Comment: Nasa has also mentioned leaving 12 cameras on the Moon, in that case, the film was taken out of the camera at one point, inside the module I suppose, then thrown out.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a test with film in the oven at moon temps. The oven caused it to draw up into itself. It could be seen at some angles a bit warped as well. If left in longer it would be obvious more damage would be caused. I Shot it on video and [posted to YouTube](https://youtu.be/4Y8Z_ioryXk). I tested 35mm film that I had around the house and thought I'd do the test and see how it does and then maybe buy some 70mm or someone watching the video might have some around the house to try.

I also read where NASA said the film was specially made, then later I saw a video where someone asked Kodak if they had it made special and they said they did not make a special film. I also read where the cameras were equipped for high heat at a [NASA history site](https://history.nasa.gov/apollo_photo.html), where more information can be found.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please explain the results of your testing without requiring us to watch the video? If the video gets taken down for some reason, this answer becomes generally unhelpful. Additionally, posting what NASA said and a link to the article in the answer is also recommended... again, we shouldn't need to go to your video to know the answer to the question. Thanks!

Comment: i added a brief of the outcome in the first paragraph

Comment: Added the link to the site that talks about the equipped cameras too

Answer (score 0):

For info, the Kodak Estar film backing starts at polyethylene terephtalate powder, extruded into sheets at 540 degrees before being stretched into rolls. At the end of the stretching process, the Kodak film backing is taken to its "heat set" temperature to lock the crystal molecular structure and create a tough PET backing that will be used for all Kodak products.